# Create a plugin or Field type

Tags: custom-fields, fieldtype

I am new to EE and working my way around the CMS. I have worked with WP and Joomla.

The task I have is to build an admin functionality where the admin can select either a URL or upload a file and this will show up as a list of links (either redirect to that URL or download the uploaded file)

Is creating a custom field type the way to go about this? Please let me if there is a sample code for this that I can follow the programming guidelines.

Thanks,

Comment: You can probably achieve this with a matrix type of field or a grid type of field. Simply have two columns (file and url) and redirect to the url or file accordingly.

Comment: Agreed, I don't think anything custom would be needed here. Welcome to ExpressionEngine :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As folks mention above, no custom development is needed here. Just use the [native Grid fieldtype](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/grid.html) with two columns - one using the File fieldtype (called, say, `file`), and the other using the Text fieldtype (called, say, `url`).

Then, in your template:

```
{my_grid_field}
    {if my_grid_field:file}<a href="{my_grid_field:file}">Download this file</a>{/if}
    {if my_grid_field:url}<a href="{my_grid_field:url}">Visit this link</a>{/if}
{/my_grid_field}
```